# Highlight table entry of a kable table upon clicking in a rmarkdown::beamer_presentation

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, beamer

In a `LaTex beamer presentation` generated with `rmarkdown::beamer_presentation`, is there a way to highlight the content of a specific cell of a `kableExtra` table upon clicking?

[image: highlights upon clicking]

### MWE

````
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
    latex_engine: xelatex
    slide_level: 2
---

```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
```

## Table
```{r table, echo = FALSE}
my_df <- mtcars[1:4, 1:2]
my_table <- kable(my_df, booktabs = T, caption = "Table caption")
my_table
```
````

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution uses `kableExtra`'s `row_spec/column_spec/cell_spec` [functionality](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf), for which several `LaTex` packages have to be loaded (e.g., via `header-includes: ...`).

[image]

The solution works with only one little thing remaining: *the table numeration increases*.
That is, the table on the first frame is numbered "1" and on the second frame with "2".
To make things really look like the added color is the only difference between both frames, the numeration would ideally be the same for both tables.

To color the rows/columns/cells as you need, see also the [rmarkdown cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kableextra.html) for more info on how to use `row_spec/column_spec/cell_spec`.

````
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
    latex_engine: xelatex
    slide_level: 2
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs} 
  - \usepackage{array}          
  - \usepackage{multirow}   
  - \usepackage{wrapfig}    
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{colortbl}    
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
  - \usepackage{tabu}
  - \usepackage{threeparttable} 
  - \usepackage{threeparttablex}
  - \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
  - \usepackage{makecell}
---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
```

## Table
```{r table, echo = FALSE}
my_df <- mtcars[1:4, 1:2]
my_table <- kable(my_df, booktabs = T, caption = "Table caption")
my_table
```

## Table {.noframenumbering}
<!-- Add "{.noframenumbering}" such that the frame number is the same on both frames -->
```{r table-with-colored-cell, echo = FALSE}
special_cell <- c(rep(F, 3), T)
colors_of_column_with_special_cell <- c(rep("black", 3), "red")

my_table %>% 
  column_spec(2, strikeout = special_cell, bold = special_cell, color = colors_of_column_with_special_cell)
```
````